Is OneDrive-backed storage really different to purely local?
I have a user with a fairly niche application. This user has an Azure-joined PC running Windows 11 Pro, and OneDrive is configured to backup (synchronise) files in Documents to the cloud.
We have found that the application works perfectly when given local file storage such as "C:\Data". However, the application fails when given local file storage in, say, "Documents", that is managed by OneDrive. This application appears to treat its files much like a multi-file database, and the software developer is adamant that OneDrive is mangling his application's data files.
There's no concurrent data sharing here - this is one person on one computer wanting to use OneDrive to provide an additional layer of protection for their data files. In practical terms I see it as a one-way synchronisation from the PC to the cloud.
I've checked that the storage directory is tagged with "Always keep on this device" (and I see a solid green circle against it and all its files), so I don't believe that "Files On-Demand" is a factor here.
I'm trying to get my head around this "OneDrive will break my files". Given this context can someone explain how OneDrive backed storage is different to local storage, please?

Without more details about what exactly breaks we can only guess what breaks in that particular application but in general there are restrictions to OneDrive folders that wouldn’t be a problem in regular directories, like certain folder names, (the name forms for example) , illegal characters and more https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/restrictions-and-limitations-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa#

@HBruijn I appreciate that, but other than the application name I don't have any more details

I’m voting to close this question because need more than "the application fails"

@GregAskew does "it crashes" provide any more detail? I literally don't have any more details available

I would think that the culprit here is the File on Demand that can cause havoc on legacy application.
The files on demand save space on the local computers, but you know the files uploaded to OneDrive get encrypted. It mean when OneDrive retrieve one file for Explorer, aka when a user click it, that the file isn't only downloaded, it's downloaded with the encryption, decrypted on the fly and placed ready for the client to open.
The goal OneDrive fulfill by doing that is for business account you can control how much time a file can be offline, after a period of time the file downloaded will be unable to be opened unless the client re-get a online connection to be able to decrypt again the file.

Thanks. I'll amend my question to clarify the files are not being pulled in through Files on Demand

@ChrisDavies If you amend the question, you could run a process monitor too and watch what happen when the application try to open file in the Document's section, you will get hinted if the encryption mechanism of OneDrive somehow get in the way of the application.

Ah, now that's a thought. Thank you

@ChrisDavies Any update on the issue, tried the process monitor logging ?

I've been away for a couple of days so my colleague has been working with the client on a different issue, but I'm hoping to get back to them (the client) early next week and see what procmon throws up

Your user would seem to be correct. What I've seen on machines that use OneDrive for a single home user with a single machine is that "synchronized" folders are actually stored in the cloud, up to the limit of OneDrive storage, and pulled down to the local machine only while they are being accessed. If you disconnect from OneDrive, and look in a synchronized folder, it will be empty except for a text file named Where are my files.txt. I don't believe that Windows Pro does it any differently, and this is part of the reason I don't use OneDrive myself.

This isn't the case here - the files are definitely local
